# Threejs - How to remove cloned collada object

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I have a collada file and loaded it.
Step1: Load collada:

```
    loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader(manager);
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load("/collada/monster.dae",
        function (collada) {
        android = collada.scene;
        skin = collada.skins[0];
        android.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    });
```

Step 2: Clone collada and add eventcontrol for remove object

```
var eventControl = initEventsControls();
cloneMonster = android.clone();
cloneMonster .position.set(100, 0, 100);
eventControl.attach( cloneMonster );
scene.add(cloneMonster );
```

Step 3: On initEventsControls() function for remove object on click

```
function initEventsControls() {
    var eventControls = new EventsControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    eventControls.map = plane;
    eventControls.attachEvent('mouseOver', function () {
        this.container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

    eventControls.attachEvent('mouseOut', function () {
        this.container.style.cursor = 'auto';
    });

    eventControls.attachEvent('onClick', function () {
        this.intersects[ 0 ].object.remove();
    });

    var Scale = new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10);
    eventControls.scale.copy(Scale);
    eventControls.offsetUse = true;

    return eventControls;
}
```

But It doesn't remove object when I click object.

How to remove cloned collada object?

Comment: object.remove() does nothing, see [object3D documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D) you have to call remove with parameter of removed object on its parent so try something like scene.remove(this.intersects[ 0 ].object) assuming the object is correctly chosen..